Why does Supervisor give an error with NGINX PHP?
I am running a project with Laravel. I use Dokploy, Docker, Nginx, PHP 7.4. From time to time there is a high load on the server. I checked the logs and see the following errors:
2024-11-28 05:25:55,583 INFO exited: laravel-queue_04 (exit status 1; not expected)
2024-11-28 05:25:55,595 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_03' with pid 1119923
2024-11-28 05:25:55,598 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_04' with pid 1119924
2024-11-28 05:25:56,437 INFO success: laravel-queue_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2024-11-28 05:25:56,437 INFO success: laravel-queue_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2024-11-28 05:25:56,552 INFO success: laravel-queue_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

The Supervisor.conf file has the following set:
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = info
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[group:laravel-worker]
priority=999
programs=nginx,php8-fpm,laravel-schedule,laravel-notification,laravel-queue

[program:nginx]
priority=10
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/access.log

[program:php8-fpm]
priority=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -R
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-access.log

[program:laravel-schedule]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/schedule.log

[program:laravel-notification]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan notification:worker
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/notification.log

[program:laravel-queue]
numprocs=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/worker.log
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=600 --tries=3

The Dockerfile file has the following set:
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/uploads

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh
RUN touch /var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log && chmod 777 /var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]

What am I doing wrong and what needs to be corrected?

You need to find out what's making the high load.  Is it related to your laravel project?  Is it related to your setup?  It's difficult to know without specifics as to what your project does.  You need to debug this issue as there's no way anyone else can.  Once you find out that it's the Laravel project, you need a log of your laravel project to discern what is high-loading/crashing.  If it isn't your project, then it is a setup issue(off topic here)
